# Using DB Method in Laravel project got DataTables error

Tags: laravel, database

I got the error in Laravel project, want to using DB method to call a database table. How to solve this?

**Error:**
DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7

Here is codes of controller

```
    public function index(Request $request)
{

    $title = 'Video Category List';

    if ($request->ajax()) {



        //$data = Category::where('type', 'Favourite')->get();
        $data = DB::table('action_status')
        ->where('type', 'Favourite')
        ->get(); 

        

        return Datatables::of($data)
            ->addIndexColumn()
            ->addColumn('name', function ($row) {
                return $row->name ?? '';
            })

            ->addColumn('image_path', function ($row) {
                return $row->image_path ?? '';
            })


            ->addColumn('status', function ($row) {
                if ($row->status == 1) {
                    return 'Active';
                } else {
                    return 'Inactive';
                }
            })

            ->addColumn('action', function ($row) {
                $btn = '<button type="button"   onclick="selectid2(' . $row->id . ')"
                class="btn btn-success waves-effect waves-light"style="margin-right:10px"   data-toggle="modal" data-target="#updatecategory">
                <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>

                </button> ';
                $btn2 = '<button type="button"   onclick="delete(' . $row->id . ')"
                 class="btn btn-danger waves-effect waves-light"style="margin-right:10px"   data-toggle="modal" data-target="#">
                 <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
                 </button>';
                return  $btn . '' . $btn2;

                // <i class="bx bx-pencil  font-size-16 align-right "   ></i>
            })


            ->rawColumns(['action'])
            ->make(true);
    }

    return view('admin/videocategory/category', compact('title'));
}
```

Comment: you need to check network tab to get more information about the error

Comment: ok, I already go network tab, what I want to copy and paste here?

Comment: yeah or put screen shot

Comment: show your ajax request

Answer (score 1):

You should start using Models in Laravel, and since you are using DataTables use jquery paired with ajax instead. Your approach is a bit complicated.

Also it is hard to debug the issue without other information from the network tab and a good test case scenario for this would be nice.

Comment: from the network tab what information should I provide here, sorry I new in Laravel

Comment: could you send a screenshot of the network tab? Maybe which of your route/s has the public function index(Request $request) ?

Comment: Seeing your source code, I believe it has something to do with a column header mismatch. 

Meaning from your controller you added a column using the addColumn(), where the column header name does on exist nor matches to your html table headers.

Comment: Add some more information like links of docs for OP to understand properly.